# Can we upload multiple files at once in Django Admin site

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin, django-file-upload

I have a class named `city`. For this city, I have a `filefield` variable to upload the files. But I need to upload multiple files all at once in a single field in the Admin site (`localhost:8000/admin`).
Could you please guide me with a sample code to get a clear idea about the implementation or suggest to me the implementation plan of doing it?

Comment: You want to upload multiple files to a single FileField?

Comment: Yes @Ersain, I want to do that in the Admin site of Django application when adding the new data.

Comment: Okay, but how do you think the single filefield will handle multiple files in it? You need a one-to-many or many-to-many relation to handle such things, then it will be no problem to add multiple input fields in admin (using either StackedInline or TabularInline)

Comment: @Ersain, I am using one-to-many relation between the City model and the file model. 
Will this works StackedInLine or TabularInLine for the issue? and multiple files upload in the sense, it can be variable.

Comment: yes, of course.